# Upgrading to ArcGIS 10.2 for Server and security vulnerability?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, installation, security

I have ArcGIS 10.1 Installed on my CentOS server and I have also installed "ArcGIS-101SP1-S-SSEC-Patch-lx" security patch.

Do I need to upgrade ArcGIS for Server to 10.2? If I don't install the latest version Would it be a vulnerability for the current version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "ArcGIS-101SP1-S-SSEC-Patch-lx" patch should be applied to **10.1 SP1**, not just 10.1 (10.1 SP1 is a standalone install, not something to be applied to 10.1).  There are more recent patches posted on [support.esri.com](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list?productid=66&productVersions=10.1&categoryTypes=5&categoryTypes=8) -- I recommend you keep up to date.

Choosing to upgrade ArcGIS Server should be part of a process that includes ArcGIS Desktop upgrades within the organization.  ArcGIS 10.2.x is subject to the "Heartbleed" OpenSSL issue, though there is both a [patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/66/metaid/2088), and a [follow-on patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/67/metaid/2101) that prevents false-positive security scans.

I'd be more worried about patching CentOS -- It's not an Esri-supported platform, and a CentOS security patch in the December time frame broke my AGS functionality to the point that I needed to install a supported RedHat release.